# How to specify read preference in Meteor's mongo queries

Tags: mongodb, meteor

In Meteor Mongo, how to specify the readPref to primary|secondary in Meteor Mongo Query.

Comment: did my answer provide you any help or does your problem still persist?

Answer (score 4):

I hope the following provides a better understanding of the relationship between Meteor and Mongo.

---

#### Meteor collections for more comfort

Meteor provides you with the full mongo functionality. However for comfort it provides a [wrapped API](https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Collection) of a mongo collection that integrates best with the Meteor environment. So if you import Mongo via

```
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo'
```

you primarily import the wrapped mongo collection where operations are executed in a Meteor fiber. The cursor that is returned by queries of these wrapped collections are also not the "natural" cursors but also [wrapped cursors](https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#mongo_cursor) to be Meteor optimized.

If you try to access a native feature on these instances that is not implemented you will receive an error. In your case:

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { Random } from 'meteor/random';

const ExampleCollection = new Mongo.Collection('examples')

Meteor.startup(() => {
  // code to run on server at startup
  ExampleCollection.insert({ value: Random.id() })
  const docsCursor = ExampleCollection.find();
  docsCursor.readPref('primary')
});
```

Leads to

```
TypeError: docsCursor.readPref is not a function
```

---

#### Accessing the node mongo driver collections

The good news is, [you can access the layer underneath](https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Collection-rawCollection) via `Collection.rawCollection()` where you have full access to the node Mongo driver. This is because under the hood Meteor's `Mongo.Collection` and it's `Cursor` are making use of this native driver in the end.

Now you will find two other issues:

1. `readPref` is named in a node-mongo cursor [cursor.setReadPreference](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/Cursor.html#setReadPreference) (3.1 API).
2. `Cursor.fetch` does not exist but is named `cursor.toArray` which (as many native operations do) returns a Promise

---

#### So to finally answer your question

you can do the following:

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { Random } from 'meteor/random';

const ExampleCollection = new Mongo.Collection('examples')

Meteor.startup(() => {
  // code to run on server at startup

  ExampleCollection.insert({ value: Random.id() })
  const docsCursor = ExampleCollection.rawCollection().find();
  docsCursor.setReadPreference('primary')
  docsCursor.toArray().then((docs) => {
    console.log(docs)
  }).catch((err)=> console.error(err))
});
```

---

#### Summary

- By using `collection.rawCollection()` you an have access to the full spectrum of the [node mongo driver API](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/)
- You are on your own to integrate the operations, cursors and results (Promises) into your environment. Good helpers are [Meteor.bindEnvironment](https://guide.meteor.com/using-npm-packages.html#bind-environment) and [Meteor.wrapAsync](https://docs.meteor.com/api/core.html#Meteor-wrapAsync)
- Beware of API changes of the node-mongo driver. On the one hand the mongo version that is supported by the driver, on the other hand the driver version that is supported by Meteor.
- Note that it is easier to "mess up" things with the native API but it also gives you a lot of new options. Use with care.